# Is the tkinter grid geometry manager idempotent?

Tags: python, tkinter, idempotent

I *believe* the widget `grid()` method is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) -- that is, if I call it multiple times, there will be no different result. I could, for instance do this:

```
widget.grid(column=0, row=0)
widget.grid_remove()
n = 100
for i in range(n):
    widget.grid()
```

This code would be the same no matter the value of n. I cannot find a definitive answer in the [tcl/tk docs](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/grid.htm), [tkdocs.com](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html#morefeatures), or the [old NMT documentation](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/grid.html).

Comment: Can I ask why this is a concern? Are you just curious? FWIW, adding `print(id(widget)` in the for loop prints the same ID each time, which means the underling (widget) object is the same. Someone correct me if I'm off-base here...

Comment: Mostly curiosity, yes. I'm binding several widget `grid` calls to buttons to update the display as the user progresses through a questionnaire. I don't think it will cause issues, but I'd like to be certain. And thanks for bringing the `id` function to my attention. That's a useful tool to have in my toolbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you call it multiple times, it will do the exact same thing each time you call it with the same parameters. The only call that has a lasting effect is the last time you call it.